# Bulk Insert In SQL Server CE

Tags: .net, sql-server, sql-server-ce

i am new at SQL Server CE and using Visual Studio 2008, SQL Server CE 3.5. I want to know that what the best way of inserting bulk records into SQL Server CE database? Does `BULK INSERT` statement work for SQL Server CE? I have nearly 45 tables and some of these tables should have large amount of data. Using `command.Prepare` is enough or is there more efficient and fast way?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

SQL CE does not have a bulk insert command.  For the best raw performance opening a an updateable [SqlCeResultset](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlserverce.sqlceresultset(VS.80).aspx) using a [TableDirect](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.commandtype(VS.80).aspx) [SqlCeCommand](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlserverce.sqlcecommand.commandtype(VS.80).aspx) is your fastest bet.  It bypasses the query processor altogether, and is actually about as fast as directly writing to a text file.

Comment: That is sort of funny though because the MSDN docs state that TableDirect is ONLY supposed to be used by OLEDB providers.  Do as I say, not as I do...
"TableDirect is only supported by the .NET Framework Data Provider for OLE DB"

Comment: Sorry stupid question - any idea if this would this be a supported scenario by MS? This seems quite interesting, I just don't want to get into the situation where MS would come back and not support if (should one require it).

Comment: TableDirect is, and always has been, officially supported by SQL CE. MS has published articles in MSDN on using it.

Answer (score 14):

I have wrapped the bulk insert code in a NuGet library, that you can use like you use SqlBulkCopy today: http://sqlcebulkcopy.codeplex.com

Comment: The nice thing with Eriks library is that the API mimics the one found in Sql2008, hence if you build different providers it would be easy to integrate.

Comment: @ErikEJ It seems like bulking parallel (via two tasks) takes the same time than bulking serially, or did I miss sth?

Comment: @c_ph_r Most likely - just use a single task

Comment: Yea can be done in one task, even serially...now I solved it using two different dbs(.sdf) which allows parallel bulking with two tasks. It's a bit ugly but much faster...thanks for your answer