# Search 1GB CSV file

Tags: c#, .net, performance, file, csv

I have a CSV file.  Each line is made up of the same format eg/

```
I,h,q,q,3,A,5,Q,3,[,5,Q,8,c,3,N,3,E,4,F,4,g,4,I,V,9000,0000001-100,G9999999990001800000000000001,G9999999990000001100PDNELKKMMCNELRQNWJ010, , , , , , ,D,Z,
```

I have a `Dictionary<string, List<char>>`

It is populated by opening the file, reading each line, taking elements from the line and adding it to the dictionary, then the file is closed.

The dictionary is used elsewhere in the program where it accepts input data into the program and then finds the key in the dictionary and uses the 24 elements to compare against the input data.

```
StreamReader s = File.OpenText(file);
 string lineData = null;
 while ((lineData = s.ReadLine()) != null)
 {
   var elements = lineData.Split(',');
   //Do stuff with elements
   var compareElements = elements.Take(24).Select(x => x[0]);
   FileData.Add(elements[27], new List<char>(compareElements));

  }
  s.Close();
```

I have just been told that the CSV file will now be 800mb and have roughly 8 million records in it.  I have just tried to load this up on my Dual Core Win 32bit laptop with 4GB of RAM in debug and it threw a `OutOfMemoryException`.

I am now thinking that not loading the file into memory will be the best bet but need to find a way to search the file quickly to see if the input data has a matching item equal to `element[27]` and then take the first 24 elements in that CSV and compare it to the input data.

a) Even if I stuck with this approach and used 16GB RAM and Windows 64bit would having that many items in a dictionary be ok?

b) Could you provide some code/links to ways to search a CSV file quickly if you dont think using a dictionary is a good plan

**UPDATE:** Although I have accepted an answer, I just wondered what people's thoughts were on using FileStream to do a lookup and then extract data.

Comment: Not an answer, just a suggestion: use a database, not a CSV file for this!! If you need single database file, SQLite is the one for you.

Comment: saving 1GB data into memory is definitely not a smart choice. You probably don't want a program to use up all your free RAM. use DBMS instead.

Comment: @Marco Are you saying that database file created is one file? If so I assume I can import the CSV file into the DB by creating a new DB file and deleting any old ones?

Comment: You could use this CSV reader: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/CsvReader.aspx

Comment: Yes. SQLite (as every database) is organized in tables and these in columns (very simple and quick description). So you should design your db and then, using a Stream, import every single CSV row in your database. Finally you must convert your app to let it use database and not CSV. SQLite is good because it doesn't need a server installed, but you can use it everywhere at runtime; more, it's a single file and license free.

Comment: @TimSchmelter I have seen that before but not sure if I can open and search the file

Comment: @Marco Makes sense but I guess I could just empty the table before I import a new CSV file.  What C# wrapper/API would you recommend?

Comment: You could use: `DELETE FROM your_table` and then (don't foget it) `VACUUM`.

Comment: @Marco How does SQL CE vs SQLLite compare? Also do you know of a C# library to communicate with SQLLite

Comment: [This site](http://sqlite.phxsoftware.com/) has C# assembly to communicate with SQLite.

Comment: @Jon: I suggested the CSV reader because it seems to to be the fastest way to import a CSV file into memory. Of course you could build a dictionary or list from the csv: `using (var csv = new CachedCsvReader(data, true)){var list = ((IListSource)csv).GetList(); // do LINQ stuff with list}`

Comment: I'd still have 1 GB in memory though and am still unsure of the performance of a dictionary/list with 8 million items in it. Do you know?

Comment: I may still use it to read the file to then do a bulk insert into a database.

Comment: @Jon: It might be perfectly valid to have 1GB in memory under certain circumstances. If not, you should use a database and [SqlBulkCopy](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/FileReader.aspx). Or maybe you even want to [parallelize import with SqlBulkCopy](http://craigwatson1962.wordpress.com/2011/02/21/parallel-load-csv-data-using-sqlbulkcopy/).

Comment: I fancy giving the parallel import a go but not sure if it would work with SQL CE

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you 're planning to search this many records, I would suggest bulk inserting the file into a DBMS like SQL Server with appropriate indices for the fields that will be your criteria, and then using an SQL query to check for the existence of a record.

Comment: Normally I would agree but this program is going out to a customer with no IT knowledge and importing that much data into a DB will need managing I feel

Comment: Then Try using simple DBMS like MS Access. Even that can help very much.

Comment: But the system should load it into a DMBS itself... as the first part of reading the file. The problem would probably be creating a structure that would be optimal.

If you could use some small lightwieght DB like SQLite that would probably be easiest

Comment: @Jon: Could you build a web app for them?  Who's in charge of the data?

Comment: I have not worked with it, but you could probably also get away with using SQL Server CE, and given that you're working with .Net, it could be a better fit into your packaging, etc.

Comment: @IoannisKaradimas CE might be a thought!

Comment: @MerlynMorgan-Graham We receive the file from the customer. This has to be Windows form based I'm afraid

Comment: @Jon Glad to be of help. Keep in mind that to properly leverage the facilities of any DBMS, you should take the time to create indices for all fields involved in comparison and sorting, and also, as I see that you have many small fields, you should keep your fields at optimal lengths as well (say three times the average value size). That way, it will never really matter how many records there are in the database.

Comment: Do you know if SQL CE supports a bulk import?

Comment: This should help you: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1539277/bulk-insert-in-sqlce]

Answer (score 0):

We had a similar problem with importing a large csv file containing data that needed to be aggregated. In the end we did a bulk insert into a SQL Server table and used SQL to perform the aggregation. It was pretty quick in the end (a couple of minutes end-to-end).

Comment: Oops, just realised that I duplicated Ioannis' answer... Must be a good idea then.

Answer (score 0):

There are several options available to you but yes, I would agree that loading this data into memory is not the best option.

a) You could load the data into a relational database although this may be overkill for this type of data.

b) You could use a NoSQL solution like [RavenDB](http://ravendb.net/). I think this may be a good option for you.

c) You could use a more efficient physical storage option like [Lucene](http://incubator.apache.org/lucene.net/)

d) You could use a more efficient in-memory/caching option like [Redis](http://redis.io/).

Answer (score 0):

A solution can be breaking the file to some smaller files and do parallel search in each file 
the order of search would be smaller or equal to n (reading whole file)

Comment: Could you demonstrate an example?

Comment: Ok,If you have FIle with 1 GB data divide it to 10 file with 100 mg and then  when user serachs run create 10 thread that runsasearch command in each file with first accurance you can stop whole search and stop it

Comment: Aha,is the value you search is unique or not? and how do you create the file?

Comment: The value should be unique. I dont create the CSV file the customer does

Answer (score 0):

As the rest of your program uses the StringDictionary entries, you still ideally need to store your results in memory - you dont really want to be querying out to a DB 1000's of times. (This could depend if your program lives on the DB server)!

I'd look into the memory usage of StringDictionary for your structure and see what your theoretical maximums are and see if you can cover this in a caveat on the functional requirements. Otherwise look for a more efficient way to store - streaming your results out to an XML file for example will be quicker to access than a DB.

Comment: Dont fully understand your answer but if I find a match between the file/dictionary and the input data I am writing a UniqueID,Pass/Fail string to a new file

Comment: you've stated "The dictionary is used elsewhere in the program" so I assume this is why you want to keep it in memory? If there is a lot of accessing of this intermediate dictionary, you wouldn't want those accesses to be across a potentially slow Database link.

Answer (score 0):

- forget MS access. Really.
- try sqlite, it will be more than adequate for a few million rows
- if you can't index your data, then don't use a  database, use an external utility like egrep with an appropriate regex to search for specific fields. It will be much faster.