# Search text from .csv file having file size more than 4TB

Tags: c#, .net, csv

I have a .csv file having a file size of more than 4TB, all records in the file are order by column FirstName. Now I want to search any name say 'test'. What will be the best approach for search?

Comment: @IvanG file store on server machine..

Comment: @nirav: Are you very sure of the size? 4 terabytes **is** very large.

Comment: 4TB? You are sure you didn't mean 4GB? Anyways, what do you mean by "best way"? What is your main concern (performance?)? How do you plan to use those matches you find? ... You will have to get a lot more specific to get useful answers. Also, show us what you have tried (considered) so far.

Comment: Here's one on how to search 1GB CSV file. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8077551/search-1gb-csv-file?rq=1

Comment: @Christian.K 4Tb can be the maximum size of file , performance is the main concern for me..I have tried solution suggest by nvoigt , but it uses linear search and it will search by each and every row of file which will be more time consuming.

Comment: @nirav You'll have to live with the fact that this will be either heavily IO or memory bound or both. Since you want to find all occurrences, and not just the first, you'll need to "see" every record. Thus reading the whole file one way or the other.

Comment: Not sure why this was closed with the reason: _"It's difficult to tell what is being asked here"_. Anyway, if the (csv)rows are sorted on FristName, a search for FirstName should be possible in less than a second using a custom binary search over the file (and the first time(s) caching some midpoints together with their FirstName), which would then leave about 25-30 seeks on the disk on average (from a max of 35 if the rows are around 200 bytes) - taking around 300ms.

Answer (score 2):

If you need a simple albeit slow search, System.Io.File and some LinQ might be enough:

```
System.IO.File.ReadLines("yourfile.csv").Where( s => s.StartsWith("test") );
```

You may improve this by doing the foreach-loop yourself so you can break after the first occurrence. For anything more sophisticated, I'd suggest you use a database. 4TB is not something that should be stored in a file with variable data length. You'd be writing half a database yourself if you wanted to do this efficiently in your code.

Comment: Ohhh, have fun with the 4TB file... this may take a while and a load of your memory

Comment: What exactly is your reason to downvote this answer? The pure fact that 4TB will take linear time? I said it's slow and that the real solution is a database.... Your comment is even downright WRONG. Read up on it, it's NOT loading it all into memory, it's reading it *line by line*.

Comment: FWIW, `System.IO.File.ReadLines` is actually not a bad choice here. It will produce output lines as it goes, and not read all lines in first. So the code above should only require that much memory, that it takes to hold those lines that actually start with `test` - which might still be too much given a 4TB(!) input file. Of course, `StartsWith` is far from proper CSV (it could be that the first field is in quotes for example), but since the OP hasn't given any more specifics, it is alright somewhat I guess.

Comment: @nvoigt I didn't downvote your answer. I simply stated the fact that it will take a while.
Still it is a solution (maybe the best, maybe not), so I won't rate it.

Comment: @nvoigt, `StartsWith` will only match the beginning. so `Mr.Test` will be missed. there's also case too.

Comment: @Christian.K: Please tell me how will you store 4TB file in memory once read till the end? i am little surprised about it

Comment: @nvoigt: For you also  "Please tell me how will you store 4TB file in memory once read till the end? i am little surprised about it"

Comment: @Saurabh: When you call `System.IO.File.ReadLines`, the content of the file is read one line at a time. After that one line is read, it is discarded (removed from memory). If therefore you do not cache it (in an array or List), it will not be saved and you will only have one line read into memory at a time.

Comment: @Saurabh You may want to look at the actual implementation of `System.IO.File.ReadLines()` (don't confuse it with `ReadAllLines()`!), it doesn't store the lines it reads. It will not cache the lines it has read over. That is one of the fundamental benefits over the newer `ReadLines()` vs. the older `ReadAllLines()`.

Comment: @Christian.K : Thanks for clearing , my bad i have not seen the differences ReadLines and ReadAllLines

Comment: @Alex Essilfie: Thanks for clearing , my bad i have not seen the differences ReadLines and ReadAllLines

Comment: +1 for nvoigt , nice use of framework