# how to import huge .csv into sql database?

Tags: c#, sql

I want to import huge .csv file about 1 gig into database.

My application is coded in c# in visual studio 2010. It is running locally and does not need to use on network.

My attempt to import only 25mb using sql compact toolbox scripts leads to crash in Visual Studio.

My attempt to use `stringbuilder` leads to an out of memory exception (usage about 4 gig of memory !) and then fails.

My attempt to import these file into Excel or Access and then convert them to database fails as well.

Which of these databases can handle better to solve my problem?

- SQL Express
- SQL Compact
- local SQL Server database

Also, which method should I use to import it as fast as I can and to load it faster into a datagridview?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Are you writing **SQL** (structured query language) and really mean Microsoft **SQL Server** (the actual product) by this? If not: **what** database system is this for?

Comment: divide the "huge" csv file into smaller pieces?

Answer (score 7):

If the CSV file does not have any strings containing commas, you can do a direct [BULK INSERT](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188365.aspx) from SQL (if it does, you will have to change the delimiter to something like a bar (`|`) character, first.   This is the most direct means of getting data from a flat file into the database, and doesn't require any intermediate programs like SSIS or Excel

I use it often, and it is the fastest and most efficient way of getting data into SQL from outside.   Your command will look something like like

```
BULK INSERT MyDatabase.dbo.MyTable 
      FROM MyFileName
           DATAFILETYPE='char',  
           FIELDTERMINATOR=',',
           BATCHSIZE=10000
```

The most common strategy is to load the data into a working table, do any clean-up / conversion necessary, and then insert it to the actual target table.

Comment: SQL CE does not have a `BULK INSERT` command. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1539277/bulk-insert-in-sqlce

Comment: Also, this method will not work when you want to map columns of csv to specific columns of destination table. You could then use a FormatFile which bulk insert can use. But, I find that too much work.

Answer (score 5):

If you really want to achieve this using C#, what you'll need to do is read the CSV line-by-line and insert it before you move to the next one.

I have a similar situation where I have to read a 2GB "CSV" (tab seperated) and load into MSSQL. Here's how I have it setup.

```
using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(@"C:\file.csv", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.None))
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(fs, Encoding.GetEncoding(1252)))
{
    if (sr.ReadLine() == null) //Take this out if you don't have a header
    {
        throw new Exception("Empty file?!");
    }

    while (sr.Peek() >= 0)
    {
          String s = sr.ReadLine();

          //SPLIT

          //INSERT SQL
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Both SQL Express, and a standard SQL Server are good candidates for your storage. And as far as what to use to import the data, use SSIS. Once you've created the database on the SQL Express or Standard SQL Server instance, right-click on that database, and under the `Tasks` menu item you'll see an option for `Import Data`. It will walk you through selecting a data source, in your case Excel, and then getting it imported into the database.

This script then, at the end of the process, can be saved.

Comment: @ The Solution : hi , and thanks for your reply but the excel has limitation on importing data. if you import 200mb into excel , it leads to crash !

Comment: @SmartMan, didn't you say you have an Excel spreadsheet you want to import **into** SQL Server? Or, let's put it this way, you would choose the appropriate Data Source during import. You could, in your case, choose a text file because it's comma-delimited.

Comment: @TheSolution: He actually said he has a .CSV file ;-)

Comment: @HardCode, sure enough. At any rate, choosing the appropriate Data Source is pretty straight forward. In this case it would be a Text File.

Comment: @neoistheone :Thanks alot :) +1

Answer (score 1):

You can use the SQLBulkImporter object in C#.
Works like a charm.

Comment: You mean `SqlBulkCopy`? The problem with `SqlBulkCopy` is you have to load all your data in memory first. Once you have a "large" csv, as the OP mentions, it can get tricky.

Comment: Also true. . .largest file I normally have is just shy of 18000 rows