# Inserting multiple rows in Webmatrix database

Tags: sql, database, razor, insert, webmatrix

I'm sure this is a comparatively simple question, but after several hours, I haven't been able to find the answer, and I'm still somewhat new to the wonderful world of databasing.

I'm starting to use Webmatrix and I'm trying to import a database with 13 columns and a little over 200 rows (just enough so I don't want to type it all out again).

All my work remains offline and won't go online for at least another few months. So far I have worked on a Mac (php, mysql,etc) and just switched to PC to try Webmatrix. Since I couldn't find a simple enough feature to import a database in Webmatrix, I figured the easiest way might be to export an SQL file from phpMyAdmin on my Mac and execute it once via a cshtml page (coding razor).

With a few adjustments I recreated my table in this way and I'm also able to insert values in individual rows, however, I can't seem to be able to insert more than one row at a time.

My intended code is basically:

```
var db = Database.Open("Database");
var insertQuery = "INSERT INTO table (field1, field2, field3) VALUES ('val1', 'val2', 'val3'),('val4','val5','val6'),(etc)";
db.Execute(insertQuery);
```

Could anyone shed some light on what might be going wrong here?
I also looked at other methods of importing databases, I read about MySQL benchmark, but admit that's going a bit over my head.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your options depend on the type of database you are using. If you are using the default WebMatrix database (SQL Compact Edition 4.0), you can save the PHP data to a csv file, and then in WebMatrix, read that using File.ReadAllLines. That will give you an array of strings each containing comma separated values representing a row of data. You can use string.Split to create an array of individual values and insert that within a foreach loop:

```
var rows = File.ReadAllLines(path_to_csv_file);
foreach(var row in rows){
    var vals = row.Split(new[]{','});
    var sql = "INSERT INTO table(f1, f2, f3) VALUES (@0, @1, @2)";
    db.Execute(sql, data[0], data[1], data[2]);
}
```

If you are using SQL Server, you can use BULK INSERT for a file. There are also a couple of other approaches for SQL CE too: [Bulk Insert In SQL Server CE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1539277/bulk-insert-in-sqlce)

Comment: Thank you for your quick and incredibly helpful answer, Mike.

I had to do a bit more research to make it all work, but with your solution as a basis it all came together.